# Multiple External IP's

Tags: windows-server-2008, firewall, nat

I have a Virtual host server that has 6 VM's on it running a Windows SErver 200i8 r2 enviroment. I have two domains externally one of which points to my static IP. How do i use my other static IP's provided by my ISP to route traffic to different internal servers?

Comment: To what? This post ends mid-sentence.

Comment: Or perhaps you meant *too*. Maybe. I'm confused now.

Comment: in other words i have static ip 1 that has a domain name ip1.com that i want pointed to one virtual server, then i have another external ip with a different domain name ip2.com that needs to route to yet another virtual server

Comment: I'm assuming you have a firewall - this config would need to be there. If you want a more specific answer, we'll need some more specific info like what kind of firewall you have. Generally though, this is setup through the NAT rules on the firewall.

Comment: I'm using a Linksys E4200

Comment: `I'm using a Linksys E4200`  Found your problem.  Expecting business-class features out of consumer-grade products.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup 1to1 Static NAT on the router for each internal server to its corresponding public IP. Your box will need to support having multiple public IP addresses assigned to it. I do not know if your Linksys supports it, as its a consumer grade box.

Comment: So I would need a Sonicwall or something similar?

Comment: Something business class that supports it. For example, i use a Watchguard XTM21 with multiple public IPs pointing to several internal web servers.